# Insert Picture to ListApp using Browse Button for computer file locations

Tags: 2013, list, sharepoint-addin, file-upload, picture

I'd like to be able to add pictures to the SharePoint listapp by simply adding the picture off my computer folders or by taking the picture.  I don't want users to have to upload the picture to a library and then add it.
(I've tried Sparqube Picture Column Lite for SharePoint 2010 app download but I'm unable to install due to corporate lockdown on downloads to our work PCs)

..........
This questions was asked 6 months ago and I'm also looking for a solution if anyone has any answers for this?

How can I set a "**browse button**" or link under the NewForm.aspx & Editform.aspx for a SharePoint 2013 list, so while users are trying to add pictures, it allows them to browse and select the picture?

Currently SharePoint 2013 (OOTB) doesn't give this option of browse for inserting picture or hyperlink, only input box to add the address manually.

It is quite cumbersome to ask user to go to the picture, copy the url of the image and paste in the picture column in the list item.

Comment: for adding link/button in edit or newform.aspx page for that you can edit that specific page of you're list in SP designer and you can add HTML/CSS/JS code there as per yoour requirment